# Missing return at end of function even if conditions are exhaustive

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(test(1, 2))
}

func test(a, b int) bool {
    if a == b {
        return true
    }
    if a > b {
        return true
    }
    if a < b {
        return false
    }
}
```

run above code i get the follow wrong message:

`./main.go:21:1: missing return at end of function`

my question is in function test, all the situation is return. why also need return at end of function.

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't know all cases are handled.

Answer (score 8):

This is regulated by the language specifications ([source](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Function_declarations)):

> If the function's signature declares result parameters, the function body's statement list must end in a **terminating statement**.

And a [terminating statement](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Terminating_statements) is defined as:

> An "if" statement in which:
>
> - the "else" branch is present, and
> - both branches are terminating statements.

Your `if` statements do not have an `else` branch, so your function body is missing the terminating statement, even if the conditions being tested may be exhaustive.

You must either add an explicit `return` at the end of the function body, or rewrite as an if-else (only `else if` is not enough):

```
func test(a, b int) bool {
    // this is a terminating statement
    if a == b {
        return true
    } else if a > b {
        return true
    } else /* a < b */ {
        return false
    }
}
```

However this kind of if-greater-or can be just written as:

```
return a >= b
```